# What are the appropriate formats for the properties of http://schema.org/GeoShape?

Tags: geocoding, semantic-web, schema.org

It would be nice if the [GeoShape](http://schema.org/GeoShape) page included examples or the individual properties were broken out instead of just being Text.

I'm specifically interested in the circle property. I want to define a circle of 20 mile (~ 32km) radius from Nottingham City Centre (52.953, -1.149).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nottingham City Neighbourhood</title>
</head>
<body>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
  <div itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoShape">
    <meta itemprop="circle" content="52.953 -1.149 32186.88"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The rich snippet tool does pick out the data, but I don't trust that I've used the right format. Especially since the parsed longitude is positive.

```
> The following structured data is viewable only in the XML results view
> in Custom Search. More information.
> 
> geoshape (source = MICRODATA)  circle = 52.953 -1.149 32186.88 
> 
> 
> The following structured data can be used to filter search results in
> Custom Search. More information.
> 
> more:pagemap:geoshape more:pagemap:geoshape-circle
> more:pagemap:geoshape-circle:1.149
> more:pagemap:geoshape-circle:32186.88
> more:pagemap:geoshape-circle:52.953
> more:pagemap:geoshape-circle:52.953_
```

As for the others, I think both box and polygon would be in the format "$lat1,$long1 $lat2,$long2 $lat3,$long3 $lat1,$long1" for a square.

Anybody have a definitive answer or reason?

Comment: The schema.org page says that GeoShape is based on [rNews](http://dev.iptc.org/rNews), and the applicable rNews documentation seems to be [this](http://dev.iptc.org/rNews-10-The-Geo-Coordinates-Class). But the examples there are even more confusing or outright broken.

Comment: I didn't even see that. 

So, rNews may have based it's geocoordinates on the docs at http://www.georss.org/simple. That makes it look like I'm using the right format. Could it be an error in Google's snippet parser?

Comment: Could be. Might be worth trying what it does for other geometries (box, etc.) and whether the output for circles makes more sense in light of that.

Comment: Looking at the output you gave, I suspect it's not really parsing the shape description according to the spec at all, but just treating it as a series of arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Please evaluate my answer. Is there anything unclear for you ?

Comment: There seems to be a GeoCircle now: http://schema.org/GeoCircle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some archaeology, following a similar trail to others.

Details: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2012Jun/0116.html

The compounding confusion seems to be (as Yves Martin points out) missing whitespace in the original rNews examples.

We'll get this situation improved and I'll report back here.

Answer (score 3):

**Validation**

The example you give (in the first version of your question) does not pass validation at http://validator.nu/. You cannot use directly a property in the same node that declares the entity type. Probably the rich snippet tool is not strict enough. To confirm, this [alternate tool](http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/) also refuses to generate a JSON expression from your block because of the lack of a top level element.

So an additional node is required for the `geo` property, here is a proper way to express it (doctype and title are for validation tool only):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Nottingham City Neighbourhood</title>
<div class="hidden" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoShape">
  <div itemprop="geo">
    <meta itemprop="circle" content="52.953 -1.149 32186.88"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Recommendation**

According to this [Google FAQ](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1093493) only few entities are really supported and based on [Organization](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146861) and [Event](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506) examples in microdata format, the optional `geo` property only propose `longitude` and `latitude` elements from http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates. So there is less doubt to use that simple *point* definition compared to `circle`. By the way this example is valid and properly extracted:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization"> 
    <span itemprop="name">Nottingham City Neighbourhood</span>
    <div itemprop="geo">
      <meta itemprop="circle" content="52.953 -1.149 32186.88"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you use [sindice.com](http://sindice.com/), there is no hit for `http://schema.org/GeoShape` whereas `http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates` is extensively used. Not so easy to find real world usage of `circle`.

**Circle property value**

For the circle property content itself, many documentation refers to [WGS84](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/) but it only concerns point. This [documentation](http://www.georss.org/simple) confirms the content text structure for the `circle` element.

This [example for rNews](http://dev.iptc.org/rNews-10-The-Geo-Coordinates-Class) obviously lacks a space before the 500 radius and is not properly rendered, the page source contains `<td class="rnews_td codestyle">38.920952 -94.645443500</td>` instead of `<td class="rnews_td codestyle">38.920952 -94.645443 500</td>`

You should look at [schema generators or parsers](http://schema.rdfs.org/tools.html). Maybe one of them has implemented a fine grain editor for GeoShape properties instead of a raw text field, so that you can confirm property content structure. I have looked at [Any23](http://developers.any23.org/) but still the same issue: GeoCoordinates is implemented but not GeoShape.

**Box and polygon property value**

No coma is expected between longitude and latitude values for point, box, polygon or line (only use space) according to both [rNews](http://dev.iptc.org/rNews-10-The-Geo-Coordinates-Class) and [GeoRSS](http://www.georss.org/simple).

**As a conclusion**, you should avoid `GeoShape` if your aim is to provide a location to search engines... At the moment, only `GeoCoordinates` seems to be a reasonable choice.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's really an answer to the question. You've followed the same chain of links to GeoRSS as Cygri and I did in the comments but added no new evidence to dispel the mistrust in the rNews examples. Also, I think the points "it's not implemented or used yet" and "use Coordinates instead of Shape" belong in the comments rather than the answer.

Comment: I first had to fix your example data and then I confirm with search of GeoShape usage in sindice.com. There is only one space lacking in "rNews", center coordinates have the same number of digits except the 500 radius which is by the way the value used in any other examples. You asked also if latitude and longitude are separated by comas, there are not. I have also looked for alternate generators and parsers to confirm the "circle" content from code sources without luck... I really spent time on it, by the way there is no other references on internet.

Answer (score 0):

Going from [the discussion on W3.org](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2012Jun/0116.html), an example value of a [GeoShape Box](http://schema.org/GeoShape) would be:

```
38.920952 -94.645443 38.951797 -94.680439
```

Those values result in the area mapped [here](http://goo.gl/maps/H1aNn).

As stated in the [schema](http://schema.org/GeoShape), they just need to be the unique values of the corners of the box (e.g. "latmin latmax lonmin lonmax"):

> A polygon is the area enclosed by a point-to-point path for which the starting and ending points are the same. A polygon is expressed as a series of four or more spacedelimited points where the first and final points are identical.

Comment: "The first point is the lower corner, the second point is the upper corner." So that's really "lonmin latmin lonmax latmax".